# Hibernate MySQL transaction configuration issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, configuration, transactions

I'm having trouble starting a transaction with Hibernate and MySQL while running in JUnit. I'm getting a HibernateException which states: "No TransactionManagerLookup specified". I believe this error is because I don't have a proper configuration setting for hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class.

I see that under the namespace of org.hibernate.transaction there are quite a few different lookup classes that I could use. All of the documentation that I could find on these was very vague. My question is what is the appropriate one for MySQL?

Comment: Please show your configuration in the testing context. When running outside the container, you generally don't use a JEE transaction manager (so no, `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` is not required in the testing context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I needed to make the following changes.

1. Changed the hibernate.cfg.xml => hibernate.current_session_context_class from jta to thread.
2. Changed the transaction manager to
   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager
   in the bean configuration.

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory">
           <ref local="sessionFactory" >
       <property>
   <bean>

Answer (score 0):

I do it with Spring and its transaction managers.  Works perfectly.

Comment: I'm a noob with Spring and Hibernate. Could you perhaps provide a simple example?